# Using 'unless defined' from puppet in ruby code

Tags: ruby, puppet

i am writing own type and provider and i want to use functionality from puppet.

How can i use `unless defined(SomeResource["test"]) {...}` in ruby code?

Thanks !

Comment: There is an intrinsic way in Ruby to do this with the Puppet module, but first it is worth asking why you want this functionality as it seems like reactive coding.

Comment: In provider i am creating another resources and one of them i should create only if some resource is defined. that's why i am asking . So, How can i use Puppet Module in ruby ?

Comment: That sounds dangerous. Could you please post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve? At least post your working code thus far.